# Is it safe to grant untrusted code "suppressAccessChecks" when -illegal-access=deny is set?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-security, java-14

Without illegal access (`--illegal-access=deny`) and denying access to `jdk.unsupported` (done using `accessClassInPackage` checks), it looks like the `ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks"` would not any longer lead to a full sandbox escape.

Is that true? Are there any other ways to compromise the security of JVM when this permission is granted to untrusted code?

Here is the setup:

- The java.policy file grants all code `ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks"`.
- The default java security manager is used. This is done by adding `-Djava.security.manager` to the VM options.
- Illegal access is forbidden, done by adding `--illegal-access=deny` to the VM options.

To be clear:

- A SecurityManger is installed. (Why do I even have to state this?)
- To load a native library you need `RuntimePermission("loadLibrary.*")` - which is not granted
- To access `sun.misc.Unsafe` you need access to the the `RuntimePermission("accessClassInPackage.sun.misc")` - which is not granted
- To access e.g. `ClassLoader.defineClass` via reflection and `setAccessible(true)`, `java.base` must open `java.lang` to your module - which it doesn't.

So either:

- Are there other ways to bypass/escape a java sandbox if the `ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks"` is granted?
- Or is the module boundary treated as a security boundary, where such a sandbox bypass would be considered a security bug?

### In short:

If I have the following policy file `my.policy`:

```
grant {
    permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
};
```

And a normal `Main.java`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

And run it with `java --illegal-access=deny -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=my.policy Main`, can the sandbox be escaped?

Comment: If you are allowing for any reflections - so no security manager or security manager that does not check for reflections, then you can never have secure environment.

Comment: The module system does not allow for deep reflection. Deep reflection is only allowed in the own module and modules that are open to the current module.

Comment: [Advanced topics under the sotms](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#advanced-topics) could be of your interest.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn but if you have access to reflections you can use unsafe and skip that rules. Or if you are able to load native libraries

Comment: `sun.misc.Unsafe` is in the `jdk.unsupported` module. Using that is forbidden, as stated in my question. Loading a native library needs an other permission that was known to enable a complete sandbox escape.